# Moving media files while preserving itunes rating in itunes

Tags: itunes

I've seen many threads on how to move an entire media collection from one machine to another.
I want to organize my mp3 directories, but any copied file loses its reference from itunes library, thus, when I add it to itunes again, it'll have no rating data.

I guess it's possible if I manipulate the itunes xml database, but I really don't want to mess with it "by hand".

Comment: What kind of organization are you looking for?  Maybe letting iTunes do it for you would be simpler?

Comment: I have a couple of hundreds files in one folder, and I need to move them to another folder without losing their rating data.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Support has instructions for moving the folder [in Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1364) and [in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449).

This method requires you to let iTunes keep your media folder organized. It sounds like you just want to move your files from one folder to another, so these instructions will work.

If you also want to organize them yourself for some reason, I'm afraid you will have to mess with it "by hand".

Comment: Thank you, I see this is the best practice solution from iTunes point of view, but once you use it iTunes "owns" you for good:)
I guess I'll have to either do it by hand/write a script or, the more reasonable option: migrate to less intrusive player.